# symputx won't let me store different macro variables with the same macro function

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to write a macro function that gets attributes from a data set, and then stores them as a macro variable. I want to write this macro function in such a way that it can be used for multiple data sets, and multiple macro variables.

What's wrong with this:

```
%macro ExtractACell(dataset, storage_var, rownum=1, var_name=Make);
data _null_;
    set &dataset. (obs=&rownum. firstobs=&rownum. keep = &var_name.);   
    call symputx(&storage_var., &var_name., "G");
    stop;
run;
%mend ExtractACell;
```

Whenever I try to run that I get notes like this:

```
 NOTE: The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 bytes long.  You might have unbalanced quotation marks.
 NOTE: The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 bytes long.  You might have unbalanced quotation marks.
 27         %let SASWORKLOCATION="%sysfunc(getoption(work))/";
```

Does `symputx` have rules against passing in macro variables that represent names of macro variables?

Comment: Can you show how you call macro? What values is storage_var equals? I think, You should use call symputx(“&storage_var.”,”&var_name”,”G”)

Comment: If the value you are storing in the macro variable is a character string longer than 262 characters, you can always use the option NOQUOTELENMAX; to suppress the warnings.  You can use a string longer than 262 characters, but SAS warns you as longer strings are sometimes the result of unbalanced quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are generating valid SAS code when your macro variables are expanded.  In particular this statement:

```
call symputx(&storage_var., &var_name., "G");
```

Would require you to call the macro with quotes around the name of the macro variable you want it to create.  Like this:

```
%ExtractACell(dataset=sashelp.cars, storage_var="mymvar", rownum=1, var_name=Make);
```

It might be simpler to code the macro using this statement.

```
call symputx("&storage_var", &var_name., "G");
```

Then you could call without the quotes around the macro variable name:

```
%ExtractACell(dataset=sashelp.cars, storage_var=mymvar, rownum=1, var_name=Make);
```

PS Your whole process is probably messed up if you need that macro.